# Word footer image alignment in VBA

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, alignment

I try to put a signature in the footer of a word document, but I can't align it at the bottom right of the footer.

Also, in my footer there is a line of text (i.e. my Company Inc) and the signature must be exactly over the text, as in the screenshot:

[image]

Any help, please?

My code, which works except for the positioning:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim SHP as String


FIRMADOC = "C:\Users\user\Pictures\1.png"


    If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If

    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If


ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter

    Set SHP = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=FIRMADOC, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
        With SHP
            'AJUSTA A "ENFRENTE DEL TEXTO"
            .ConvertToShape
            ' MANTIENE EL RATIO
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            'AJUSTA A ANCHO 1 inch
            .Width = InchesToPoints(1)
    '        .Alignment = ' need this code for bottom-right, PLEASE

        End With
   ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Shape` objects "float" on the page, they can be easily positioned. They can also be easily (and accidentally) repositioned. `Shape` objects can also be tricky to hanlde using code. So a useful rule-of-thumb I use is: if an `InlineShape` works, use it rather than a `Shape`.

Three possibilities are out-lined, below; two for InlineShapes and one for a Shape.

An `InlineShape` can be positioned right-aligned to the page using two different methods (depending on whether it's alone in the paragraph).

1. Right-align the paragraph which contains the `InlineShape`. This is appropriate when the paragraph has no other content. Extracting just the code from the question for handling this:

```
Dim SHP as InlineShape

Set SHP = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=FIRMADOC, _
                    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
SHP.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
```

2. If the paragraph has other content to the left, then a right-aligned TAB stop with a TAB character preceding the `InlineShape` will work. A **Footer** by default has two TAB stops: one center-aligned, the second right-aligned.

For this, I'm going to change the entire code in the question in order to optimize working in a Footer. (The same approach applies to a Header BTW). The macro recorder produces code that emulates user actions, so it actually opens up the footer (or header) using things like `ActiveWindow` and `Selection`. These are somewhat difficult to control precisely; working with the actual Word objects is more reliable.

Think of a `Range` object like an invisible selection. The entire Footer area is assigned to a range (`rng`). Since the Footer already has content (the "Company Inc" text), it's necessary to "collapse" the `Range`. (Think of it like pressing left-arrow so that new content does not replace a selection.)

Then two TAB characters are added to it (`rng.Text = vbTab & vbTab`) and the signature is added.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim FIRMADOC as String
  Dim SHP as InlineShape
  Dim rng as Word.Range

  FIRMADOC = "C:\Users\user\Pictures\1.png"

  Set rng = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range 
  rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart 
  rng.Text = vbTab & vbTab 'position at second, right-aligned tab in the footer)  
  Set SHP = rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=FIRMADOC, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=rng)
  With SHP
    ' MANTIENE EL RATIO
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    'AJUSTA A ANCHO 1 inch
    .Width = InchesToPoints(1)
  End With
End sub
```

3. If it's necessary to use a `Shape` object, then a combination of the `Left` and `RelativeHorizontalPosition` properties is required. Members of the `wdShapePosition` and `WdRelativeHorizontalPosition` enumerations specify these special settings.

Note that it also might be necessary to include the `Top` property to get the correct vertical position of the `Shape` to the "Company, Inc" text.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim FIRMADOC as String
  Dim SHP as InlineShape
  Dim rng as Word.Range

  FIRMADOC = "C:\Users\user\Pictures\1.png"

  Set rng = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range  
  rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
  Set SHP = rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=FIRMADOC, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=rng)
  Set SHP = SHP.ConvertToShape
  With SHP
    ' MANTIENE EL RATIO
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    'AJUSTA A ANCHO 1 inch
    .Width = InchesToPoints(1)
    .Left = wdShapeRight '-999996
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin '0
  End With
End sub
```

Comment: @G.Asins Wonderful :-) Glad we could work it out! I'm going to do some minor editing to both the Question and the Answer so that everything is clearer for future visitors having a similar problem.