# How to center a logo image into Word 2016 footer?

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer, text-alignment

I want to center a logo image in the footer of a Word 2016 document.

Based on code from [Word footer image alignment in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257052/word-footer-image-alignment-in-vba), I can get the logo into the footer but cannot get it centered.

```vb
Sub Main()
'Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257052/word-footer-image-alignment-in-vba
  Dim FIRMADOC As String
  Dim SHP As InlineShape
  Dim rng As Word.Range

  FIRMADOC = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Documents\Invoice\footer.png"

  Set rng = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
  rng.Text = vbTab & vbTab 'position at second, right-aligned tab in the footer)
    ‘(Note: I have tried removing the tabs to no useful effect)
  Set SHP = rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=FIRMADOC, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=rng)
  
'Based on Record Macro
      ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
    Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\16\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" _
        ).BuildingBlockEntries("Bold Numbers 3").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
        RichText:=True
End Sub
```

The image ('FIRMADOC') ends up left justified. Manually changing alignment from Home Tab works. Recording that manual change comes up empty.

Comment: Include a tab key before the logo. (Delete one of your vbTab characters.) The footer style in Word has a center tab set.

Comment: Save yourself much pain and anguish. For headed and footers I always use a table. Put a single row three column table in the footer. Set the middle cel to centered and away you go.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesKenyon, I removed one of the vbtabs, but got the same result. Thinkng it might be the "Page X of Y", I removed that, but still stayed left. Macropod's solution worked so I am going with that.

Comment: Thank you @freeflow. Because all of the subforms that use the document populate the base document with Building Blocks that contain one or two tables themselves, I was a bit reluctant to try your approach. Since Maropod's solution does the trick, I'll go with that. But I do appreciate your response and will try it out as a test case. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Dim Shp As Shape
With ActiveDocument
    Set Shp = .Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Documents\Invoice\footer.png", _
        LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Anchor:=.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range)
    Shp.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
    Shp.Left = wdShapeCenter
End With
```

or, if you want the logo formatted as in-line:

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Documents\Invoice\footer.png", _
        LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=.Characters.Last
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @macropod. Worked like a charm. At 77 years old, I do not anticipate writing any more applications, but I will spend quite some time studying your answer. I am truly grateful.